# activating a class in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

OK,

so i have a class called "turret" in a tower defense game and another class called 
"turret2" what i want is so that when you press the "1" key and click on the stage a turret is placed and when you click the "2" key turret 2 is placed can someone help me with this ?( or maybe point me towards another tutorial for a tower defense game)

this is  another class called "Emptyblock" (Place that i put the turrets) the system didnt find any errors so...

```
package {


//importing required classes for this to work
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
public class EmptyBlock extends MovieClip {//defining the class as EmptyBlock
    private var _root:MovieClip;//creating a _root variable to access root easily
    private var turretone:uint=49;
    public function EmptyBlock() {//this function will always run once EmptyBlock is called
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);//create a function that will run once
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrameEvents);//create a enterFrame function
    }
    private function beginClass(e:Event):void {
        _root=MovieClip(root);//setting the _root as the root level

        this.buttonMode=true;//make this act like a button
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, thisMouseOver);//adding function for mouseOver
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, thisMouseOut);//adding function for mouseOut
        this.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, turret1);

    }
    private function eFrameEvents(e:Event):void {
        if (_root.gameOver) {//remove this and listeners if game is over
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrameEvents);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, thisMouseOver);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, thisMouseOut);
            this.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, turret1);
            MovieClip(this.parent).removeChild(this);
        }
    }
    private function thisMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //changing the background so the user know's it's clickable
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x009900);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
    private function thisMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //changing the background back
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
    function turret1(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode==turretone) {
            _root.makeTurret(this.x,this.y);//make the turret
            //remove all the listeners so it can't be clicked on again
            this.buttonMode=false;
            this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
            this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
            this.graphics.endFill();
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, thisMouseOver);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, thisMouseOut);
            this.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, turret1);


        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class that manages your keyboard input and holds the current items you can use. Once you press a key the class switches to the item that is linked to that key. You should really consider splitting up your code into smaller manageable blocks.

```
// tools swaps active tool class when pressing keyboard
_tools = new ToolManager(stage); // pass stage to class enabling keyboardEvent
_tools.addTool(turrentType1, 49); // bind class to keyCode
_tools.addTool(turrentType2, 48); // bind class to keyCode

// quick listener for click
_board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoardClick);


private function onBoardClick(event : MouseEvent) : void
{
  //create new using something like new _tools.activeTool();
}
```

Comment: im still a little confuse with this 1) what is tools 2) what is board